# What does 3Q8 mean in the aircraft model Boeing 767-3Q8?

Tags: boeing

I have aircraft types like `Boeing 767-3Q8`, `Boeing 767-33A`, `Boeing 767-3P6ER` and many others. I know what `ER` means. But what is coded as `3Q`, `33A`, `3P6` etc.?

How can I convert it back to more common types like `Boeing 767-300`? Just replace last two symbols with `00`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Those are Boeing's customer codes. They denote which airline the aircraft was originally built for, not necessarily the airline that owns/operates the aircraft currently. For example, Southwest's customer code is H4 but they operate some 737-7BD's, which are from the AirTran acquisition. In your case, the Q8 means it was originally built for ILFC, a leasing corporation.  A full list is available here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Boeing_customer_codes

Your assumption about replacing the customer code with 0s to get the plain old model is correct.

Comment: Technically the code indicates a customer configuration, rather than a customer. E.g. KLM took delivery of several 737-8K2 and -9K2 models (Transavia customer code) that were ordered in a single batch with Transavia's own (Transavia got 737-7K2 and -8K2 models, no -9K2).

Comment: As an aside, it is interesting to note that on the 787 it seems that Boeing has decided not to include the customer code at all and simply denote the model as '787-8' (for example) [source](http://worldairlinenews.com/2012/08/02/first-looks-an-inside-look-at-united-airlines-new-boeing-787-8-dreamliner/)