# What is a 73W aircraft

Tags: airliner

With all the issues surrounding the Ethiopia crash can you tell me what a 73W is?  Is it a 737 Max 8.  We're trying to figure out if our flights with Westjet on Friday might be effected.

Thanks

Frank N

Comment: It won’t be affected as you won’t be flying on a 737 MAX then.  Both the FAA and Transport Canada grounded all 737 MAX flights in their respective jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=241063 (and others) B73W is a newer version of Boeing 737-700. A one with winglets installed.
So, it's not B737 MAX 8.

A more comprehensive list (which sadly does not include 73W) is here [What is the difference between Boeing 73G, 73H and 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14034/what-is-the-difference-between-boeing-73g-73h-and-737).

Comment: the thread is from 15 years ago though ;)

Comment: @ymb1 Might not change the fact :D

Answer (score 0):

73W describes [a 737-700 with winglets](http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/arctypes.asp). This is an older model and not a 737 MAX model. It is not covered by recent regulatory actions.

[Most of Westjet's fleet is not impacted](https://blog.westjet.com/westjet-737-max-questions-and-answers/?sm_cid=social:ws-world:737maxupdate:twitter), though they will be shuffling flights around to different aircraft types, so there's no guarantee your flight couldn't see some effects, but it should be less likely.